# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Laravel Schedular Job

Tags: laravel, foreach, cron, scheduler, invalidargumentexception

I'm working with `Schedular` in `Laravel 5.8`. after setting up the `Commands` and `Command Kernal` I'm getting the error as,

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() at /home/SERVER_USER_NAME/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php:261)

Here is the `Kernal` methods,

```php
protected $commands = [
    Commands\OfferMonitor::class,
    Commands\RankingCommand::class,
    Commands\CreditCycle::class,
];

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('KG:OfferMonitor')->dailyAt('01:00');
    $schedule->command('KG:UpdateRanks')->everyTenMinutes();
    $schedule->command('KG:CreditCycle')->dailyAt('00:00');
}
```

Here is my `Laravel Cron Job` running on production server,
[image: Cron Job]

I think the cron job itself throws an error, I'm using `php` binary instead of `php-cli`. Does it caused error? if yes, what's the workaround to this issue?

Here is the complete error log and stacktrace from Laravel,

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() at /home/SERVER_USER_NAME/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php:261)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/SERVER_USER_NAME/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php(261): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Invalid argumen...', '/home/SERVER_USER_NAME...', 261, Array)
#1 /home/SERVER_USER_NAME/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(970): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput->getFirstArgument()
#2 /home/SERVER_USER_NAME/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(81): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->getCommandName(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput))
#3 /home/SERVER_USER_NAME/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(133): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#4 /home/SERVER_USER_NAME/public_html/artisan(36): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#5 {main}
"}
```

> Note: The `Commands` scheduled in `Kernal.php` is running properly when I use them with `artisan` from terminal, so there is no issue about command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the cron command as this

```
/usr/local/bin/php register_argc_argv=1 artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: It's already added as a `cron` (according to given in Docs). In another project, the same procedure works well.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting register_argc_argv (ini config var) as 1 using -d flag

```
php -d register_argc_argv=1 artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php -d register_argc_argv=1 artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Also create php.ini file in your /path-to-your-project with

```
register_argc_argv = On
```

Comment: It works with php cli version without using `register_argc_argv` flag in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Create a php.ini file in your project root

> eg: /public_html/myproject

Add `register_argc_argv = On` in your `php.ini` file that you already created

Thats all

Answer (score 0):

This **command** line worked for me, hope it helps.

```
/usr/local/bin/php ~/public_html/artisan reminder:users >> /dev/null 2>&1
```